# Node Express paths are not being matched on production (Heroku)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

This question has been asked many times, I've checked all the usual causes of this - and still can't resolve the issue. See the debug steps below for the usual causes & attempted solutions.

I have a **React app** (built from create-react-app), a **Node Express server**, and I deploy them on **Heroku**.

The entire repo is public [here](https://github.com/SarahJoline/haiku-4-u).

You can view the live production page [here](http://haiku4u.herokuapp.com/).

#### Here is the problem:

The React app loads fine. On app load, we make an API call to "GET /api/haikus" which returns an error. ([view App.js code](https://github.com/SarahJoline/haiku-4-u/blob/master/src/App.js#L20))

The API call's error says `Unexpected token < in JSON`. We inspect the network response, and see our React app's `index.html` page.

I also used PostMan to directly do a `GET /api/haikus` to see if my browser or react was messing with it. I still get the same response (ie the index.html page).

For Express apps, this usually means your routes are in the wrong order (e.g. `app.get("*", ...)` is getting hit before your API routes).

So I checked the routes in my [server.js](https://github.com/SarahJoline/haiku-4-u/blob/master/server.js) file. They're in the right order with the `/api` routes above the general `*` route.

So why is my server not matching any routes **only in production?**

Comment: your server running on 8080, and you are not server side rendering, your domain is pointing to your static folder but you need your nginx to proxy /api/ to your port 8080

Comment: Not a downvoter here but none of your routes seem to work but the default route. Are you sure you deployed the github code there? What if you comment out this default `*` route?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial - my server is only running on 8080 in develop. On production, it runs on whatever port is provided as env var from Heroku. See server.js where we conditionally listen on the environment port. Also I'm not using Nginx.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - thanks for the idea, if I comment out the `*` route, the React app isn't served at all as expected. A console.log added to server.js still shows the route being hit when I leave the `*` route in.

Comment: Forget the react app for a moment. What happens to the /api/haikus route then? Is it served correctly?

Comment: Did you tried to go directly to the api route with fiddler or something and see what's going on?

Comment: @OrAssayag and WiktorZychla good call - I did test with PostMan. I get the same response as in the React app.

Comment: I think your API is not running at all. Reasons can be not connecting to DB. Can you check heroku logs (heroku logs tail)

Comment: Thanks @IRSHAD - if my 'API' wasn't running at all, then even the default route would fail. NodeJS just sees a bunch of routes, not a distinction between the ones I use as an 'API' and the one serving my index.html file.

Comment: Can you verify the mongoDB got connected? Verify the heroku logs, and check whether the message you had given "connected to mongoDB" is being printed or not.

Comment: @IRSHAD yes, I'm connected to MongoDB. Looked at Heroku Logs, no errors, just successful 200 responses from "/api/haikus"... returning the result from the wrong route.

Comment: Request to "api/haikus" responds with Server: Cowboy. Upon further research this is an erlang webserver that Heroku uses https://github.com/heroku/cowboyku. Are you using any add-ons or buildpack in your project? Also try renaming "procfile" to "Procfile", it might be case sensitive. Can you show us the Heroku builds logs of your last deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server.js file is already written to serve the static files for react (build folder) and also to serve API response. But in your package.json file, I could see only you are running 'serve -s build' which will serve the react files and not trigger the node server which gives API response.

So you may have to run the server.js as your 'npm start' script and it will serve both API as well as react files (from build folder).

So try changing npm script in package.json as follows and redeploy to heroku.

```
"start": "node server.js",
```

Comment: Ah interesting - let me give that a shot and get back to you!

Comment: do you want to do a video call ?  i will help you figure this out quickly ! dolev146@gmail.com

Comment: Hey @IRSHAD, this was it! Can't believe I didn't double check what I was actually doing in my package.json, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

what's up! the problem is that Heroku run different commands to run your app in his server ,

in the repo you showed us

you don't have a ****build** folder** that is created after running

`npm run build`

**AND YOU HAVE BOTH SERVER CODE AND REACT CODE ON THE SAME FOLDER!!**

**please separate server folder and react to a different folder.**

quick solution i cant give you because ****deploying is a long process** but** this is what you need to go through in order to deploy and get you app to work

check this guide on how to upload this is the best solution i can give you

[Article](https://dev.to/myogeshchavan97/how-to-deploy-react-node-js-application-to-heroku-4jb4)

and if you want

**i will happily help you on a video call**

**Gmail google meets
dolev146@gmail.com**

-----------------------------EDIT

check out this video i made you !

[How to Deploy to heroku YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRMN7FXyE44&t=426s)

Comment: Hey Dolev! Appreciate the answer. So "heroku-postbuild" creates the build folder after the app is deployed to heroku. Also it is fine to have server code and react code in the same root folder, although often people will have entirely separate repos for it - this in itself does not create a problem. The issue turned out to be the "npm start" command defined in my package.json was still using a static file server (the NPM package called Serve) instead of actually starting my node server.